# How can we construct C between A and B s.t. AB = α AC with compass-straightedge method?

Tags: geometry

How can we construct $C$ between $A$ and $B$ such that $\vec{AB}=\alpha \vec{AC}$ where

- $\alpha=\sqrt{3/2}$ and
- $\alpha=\pi$?

The constraints is that we have to use the strict version of the geometrical construction with compass-straightedge method. The compass will collapse whenever it leaves the drawing plane.

I totally have no idea as the number $\alpha$ is difficult to produce, especially the second case.

Comment: This is equivalent to constructing a line of length $\alpha^{-1}$

Comment: "Obviously" this is not possible when $\alpha=\pi$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: How about the circumference of a semi-circle? Can we take advantage of it?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the following figure can help you draw the first case.

[image]